# Kotlin's logical 'and' doesn't short-circuit?

Tags: kotlin

I was following along Kotlin's documentation at http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions and tried adapting this example,

```
val b = "Kotlin"
if (b != null && b.length > 0) {
    print("String of length ${b.length}")
} else {
    print("Empty string")
}
```

to the case where `b = null`. In an IntelliJ Idea Kotlin project I have an `app.kt` with a `main()` function defined as:

```
fun main() {
    val b = null
    if (b != null && b.length > 0) {
        print("String of length ${b.length}")
    } else {
        print("Empty string")
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get two compilation errors:

```
Information:Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.3.20 (JRE 11+28)
Information:2019-02-02 15:07 - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 1 s 921 ms
/Users/kurtpeek/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/src/app.kt
Error:(3, 24) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: length
Error:(4, 37) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: length
```

I understand that the compiler is evaluating `b.length` even though the first condition, `b != null`, is `false`. This surprises me because I thought that the first check was to 'short-circuit' the Boolean expression if needed and make the call to `b.length` 'safe'.

For example, in Python, you can do this:

```
In [1]: "foo" == "bar" and what.the.heck
Out[1]: False
```

which works even though `what` is not defined, because the `and` 'stops' since `"foo"` is not equal to `"bar"`.

Is this indeed how Kotlin works? It seems like missing Python's 'short-circuiting' feature would be a limitation.

Comment: In Kotlin, we have `&&`, but we also have `and`. `&&` will perform a short circuit evaluation. `and` will not. Using `if (false && false)` as an example, the evaluation will stop at the first `false` because it already knows the outcome will be `false`. With `if (false and false)`, both booleans will still be evaluated even though logically you could know the outcome is `false` from the first. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/and.html: "...Unlike the && operator, this function does not perform short-circuit evaluation. Both this and other will always be evaluated."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kotlin's `&&` operator will short circuit (just like Java's) but only at runtime. What you are experiencing is a *compile time* error. The big difference to remember especially when comparing Kotlin (or Java) to Python is that Kotlin and Java are statically typed and have a compilation phase. So you'll get a compilation error if the types don't match up.

Let's go through these one at a time...

```
val b = "Kotlin"
if (b != null && b.length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

In this case, Kotlin will correctly infer that `b` is the type `String`, because you clearly set it to a String ("Kotlin"). We should note here that the `String` type cannot ever contain null. Knowing that, the `b != null` part of your `if` statement is unnecessary. However, after evaluating that (to true, always) it will evaluate `b.length` because `b` is a `String` and therefore has a `length` property. This example *should* compile fine (I didn't test it).

And next...

```
val b = null
if (b != null && b.length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

This code will not compile, let's go over why...

This code looks *really* similar but has one huge difference. In this case because you just set `b` to `null`, Kotlin is going to infer that `b` is an `Nothing?`. It has no information as to what type you want `b` to be, and you've set it to null (and because it's a `val`, it will *always* be `null`). Because `b` is `null`, it makes `b` nullable.

So, given that, when we compile `b != null`, that will *always* fail, because `b` can't ever be something that isn't `null`. But wait! We're compiling now... and when we run into `b.length` Kotlin will throw a *compilation error* because `Nothing?` does not have a `length` property!

Essentially, by setting `b` to `null` and not providing a type hint, Kotlin takes the only path it can to infer the type - `Nothing?`.

Comment: In Kotlin, nullables are handled differently. Please see: https://kotlinexpertise.com/kotlin-nullability-features/

Comment: That makes sense, I set `val b: String? = null` to make `b` a nullable string (not an `Any?`) and the example worked.

Comment: Yup, it's actually `Nothing?`. My bad. Corrected, thanks!

Comment: `&&` will short circuit. `and` will not.

Answer (score 1):

From your linked text: "Note that this only works where b is immutable (i.e. a local variable which is not modified between the check and the usage or a member val which has a backing field and is not overridable)".

`val b=null` is immutable, but since the type of null cannot be inferred nor stored, it cannot be used as the source in a valid shortcut.

If you changed to code to give it a nullable type, and set that null, this would work.

Comment: This is incorrect in two ways: 1. `b` _is_ "a local variable which is not modified between the check and the usage". 2. "a nullable type" would include `Any?` or `Int?`. If you gave `b` one of those types, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov,  1.   You are correct. My the documented reasoning contains a flaw. Thank you for pointing that out. I will fix that.  2. Just as long as it is a Kotlin nullable type , it does work.  `val b: String? = null`  or  `val b: Int? = null`

Comment: 2. No, it doesn't. With `val b: Int?` the line `b != null && b.length > 0` won't compile, try it. 3 (which I forgot to think of immediately). The type of null can be inferred. If it couldn't, then the line `val b = null` itself would give an error.